# "This Account lacks sufficient permissions" DocuSign

Tags: php, api, soap, docusignapi

Not sure how many people here use docusign but I am having a bit of a issue creating and sending a envelope and sending to docusign when I send this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateAndSendEnvelope</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To>https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx</wsa:To>
        <wsa:MessageID>uudi:1e1929b6-2adc-ed07-413f-4e766500ef88</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Created>2012-03-22T20:18:07Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2012-03-22T20:23:07Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>87a3ac71-f806-4eff-ad67-7f39e5cfac42</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">testpasword</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>CiT5a2eGKY/o6OfdfdJHQA31rslk3Z4xrLxHYyUMC4p4=</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2012-03-22T20:18:07Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
            <ns1:Envelope>
                <ns1:AccountId>4dfg3432-4331-49d5-8ca0-2c431f6b376</ns1:AccountId>
                <ns1:Documents>
                    <ns1:Document>
                        <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>
                        <ns1:Name>Document</ns1:Name>
                    </ns1:Document>
                </ns1:Documents>
                <ns1:Recipients>
                    <ns1:Recipient>
                        <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>
                        <ns1:UserName>Company Name</ns1:UserName>
                        <ns1:Email>anthony.gordon@email.com</ns1:Email>
                        <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>
                        <ns1:AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
                        <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>
                    </ns1:Recipient>
                </ns1:Recipients>
                <ns1:Tabs>
                    <ns1:Tab>
                        <ns1:DocumentID>1</ns1:DocumentID>
                        <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>
                        <ns1:PageNumber>1</ns1:PageNumber>
                        <ns1:XPosition>100</ns1:XPosition>
                        <ns1:YPosition>100</ns1:YPosition>
                        <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>
                    </ns1:Tab>
                </ns1:Tabs>
                <ns1:Subject>Test message</ns1:Subject>
                <ns1:EmailBlurb>personal message to send</ns1:EmailBlurb>
            </ns1:Envelope>
        </ns1:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] This Account lacks sufficient permissions
```

This is the returning message that docusign sends to me. Yes I created a demo account. 
I am following this tutorial

```
https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Create-And-Send-Envelope
```

I notice that the tutorial does not pass a integration key. Could this possibly be the reason

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, does not mention in start up tutorial. One thing that is crucial is you must append the key to the username and the key must be within brackets

```
$api->setCredentials("[".$key."]".$username, $password);
```