# Docusign API - "This Account lacks sufficient permissions"

Tags: api, docusignapi

I have tried the solution in this post: 
    ["This Account lacks sufficient permissions" DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830067/this-account-lacks-sufficient-permissions-docusign)

I'm having the same trouble as this user: 
    http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-PHP/This-Account-lacks-sufficient-permissions/td-p/17525

Everything is checked:
Account-Wide Rights
Send On Behalf Of Rights (API)
Sequential Signing (API)

I notice user's issue was fixed when Ergin enabled  "Embedding".  Is this in option that must be turned on by Docusign?  I could not locate it in the Admin.  Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

how long ago did you create your DocuSign demo account?  If it was created before April 2013 then this error might be due to the Embedding functionality you've mentioned and we would have to enable this option for you from DocuSign's side.

If you've created this account April or later then that option should be turned on your account, and you might be having an issue with your authentication.  Are you using the SOAP api or the REST api?  They have different authentication methods between the two.  Also, please post your API account ID so we can check your account settings.  Feel free to email me if you don't want to share (ergin.dervisoglu@docusign)

One last thing... please start using DocuSignAPI tag when you post here.  The DocuSign tag should be used for non-technical DocuSign questions...