# DocuSign SOAP Api exception “This Account lacks sufficient permissions”

Tags: docusignapi

I created demo account on docusign demo site some days ago and I have the same problem ["This Account lacks sufficient permissions" DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830067/this-account-lacks-sufficient-permissions-docusign).

Could you guys help me out of this? I really appreciate your help.

**Update SOAP trace:**

*CreateAndSendEnvelope request*

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateAndSendEnvelope</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<Envelope>
<AccountId>5b119284-64fd-4f85-877c-8825b2e73bc1</AccountId>
<Documents>
<Document>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>a2a7b1a3efd6416ab00742a72cd00b97_DOCUSIGN_DATA.pdf</Name>
<PDFBytes></PDFBytes>
</Document>
</Documents>
<Recipients>
<Recipient>
<ID>1</ID>
<UserName>TEST 1 LAST</UserName>
<Email>TRUNGNGUYEN@INTERACTIVECONTACTCENTER.COM</Email>
<Type>Signer</Type>
<AccessCode xsi:nil="true"></AccessCode>
<RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
</Recipient>
</Recipients>
<Subject>sign</Subject>
<EmailBlurb></EmailBlurb>
</Envelope>
</CreateAndSendEnvelope>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

*CreateAndSendEnvelope response*

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<HttpResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>Internal Server Error</StatusDescription>
<WebHeaders>
<Vary>Accept-Encoding</Vary>
<Strict-Transport-Security>max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains</Strict-Transport-Security>
<Content-Length>1394</Content-Length>
<Cache-Control>private</Cache-Control>
<Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
<Date>Wed, 25 Sep 2013 16:03:23 GMT</Date>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpResponse>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e12ae2b6-6328-4b5b-b553-95f422f66454</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9f37c1cf-d875-4acd-9b88-108e9b11efc2</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-14c52cbb-7b93-4541-9867-c16654c1629b">
<wsu:Created>2013-09-25T16:03:24Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2013-09-25T16:08:24Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns="">soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring xmlns="">This Account lacks sufficient permissions. </faultstring>
<faultactor xmlns="">missing in Web.Config</faultactor>
<detail xmlns="">
<ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">111</ErrorCode>
<ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">This Account lacks sufficient permissions.</ErrorReason>
</detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Comment: What api call are you trying to make when you receive this error message?  Show any relevant code you may have...

Comment: @Ergin: I call **CreateAndSendEnvelope** api. I can't post bunch of my code here, so I'll tel you the flow: there are a lot of documents on our site that need customer to sign, so we send out the document to the customer need to sign and get that signed document back on our system. I use **RequestStatus** and **RequestPDF** to check and get document. My account info, username: trungnguyen@interactivecontactcenter.com, and account id: 5b119284-64fd-4f85-877c-8825b2e73bc1

Comment: Could anyone work for DocuSign help me out? Please.

Comment: Usually when we see this error it's because Embedding functionality is not enabled on a given account, however your account has it enabled so this must be something else.  You're getting the error on the **CreateAndSendEnvelope** call right?  What are doing special in there?  Any unique recipients or tabs or anything?  Or any advanced features you are trying to utilize in the call?

Comment: Please post a SOAP trace of your call so we can inspect...

Comment: @Ergin: before call **CreateAndSendEnvelope** api, we use code to create some tabs (type **SignHere** or **InitialHere**) and insert them to document where user need to sign, then we send that document to docusign server. There are maybe some recipients need to sign that document.

Comment: SOAP trace: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: This Account lacks sufficient permissions. 

Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Comment: Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at bin.DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap.CreateAndSendEnvelope(Envelope Envelope)
   at bin.DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoapClient.CreateAndSendEnvelope(Envelope Envelope)

Comment: That's the call stack, I would need the SOAP trace to be able to determine anything.  I need to see what options you are using in your request that gets sent, basically the SOAP body that goes out.  There are lots of tools out there that will create one for you and output in XML format...

Comment: @Ergin: I've updated the SOAP trace to my original post. Please take a look

Comment: I've gone through your account and enabled a couple of extra settings, but I don't see anything in your trace that stands out so I'm not sure which option it might be yet.  The only thing I can think of is the authentication - it looks like you are generating an access code.  As a test can you try without that?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are trying to use a feature or setting that is not enabled on your demo account.  By default DocuSign enables all features on demo accounts so I'm not sure how your account got into a weird, semi-activated state.

*In most situations this needs to be fixed by DocuSign on their side by someone going into your account and enabling a feature or setting*.

I've gone through your account and enabled some things that should have been turned on, please try again.

Comment: It looks like the way we call login api first and then call CreateAndSendEnvelope api make that exception. I just remove the code to call login api and it solves the problem. Thank you for you time helping me out, Ergin.